# How can I get nearest occupied point from map?

Tags: navigation, mapping, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to write simple node of particle filter for Gazebo model of robot with diff drive and sonar sensors.
I use map_server node to load map. I need method (or node) to get nearest occupied point from map to defined direction. It means, I would like model of sonar sensor on map.
Is there such possibility in ROS?

Best Regards,
Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51645/how-can-i-get-nearest-occupied-point-from-map?/) by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on ROS Answers with karma: 641 on 2013-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will have to create your own node that subscribes to the map (OccupancyGrid) from the map_server, on topic /map. Once you have that you can find out which cells in the map are occupied.

---

Originally posted by [HammyG](https://answers.ros.org/users/4052/hammyg/) with karma: 51 on 2013-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1634/johannes-meyer/) on 2013-02-08**:
The [hector_map_server](http://ros.org/wiki/hector_map_server) package from the hector_slam stack contains a node, that advertises a service to retrieve the distance to the nearest obstacle, given a source frame_id and point to specify the direction. You can use it directly or take it as an example.

**Comment by [HammyG](https://answers.ros.org/users/4052/hammyg/) on 2013-02-09**:
Awesome! That will come in handy for me.